# Where to mount EFI partition?

Tags: mount, boot-loader

I have an existing EFI partition used for a Windows installation.
I want to install GRUB to it, for dual boot.

The tutorials say to mount this efi-partition (in my case `/dev/sdb1`) to `/mnt/boot`.

Now my question is, to which `/mnt/boot` should I mount?

I am in a shell from a Linux on a USB stick.

Should I make a directory `/mnt/boot` inside the persistent Linux installation that I want to boot? I can just do that by mounting it first.
Or should I make a volatile directory `/mnt/boot` from the shell of the USB stick and mount the boot partition there?

I hope I described my question in an understandable way. Another way to describe it:

Should I create `/boot/efi` inside the root partition containing the Linux I want to boot, using the following commands?

```
root@archiso ~ # mkdir my_mountpoint
root@archiso ~ # mount /dev/<root_partition> my_mountpoint
root@archiso ~ # mkdir my_mountpoint/boot/efi
root@archiso ~ # mount /dev/sdb1 my_mountpoint/boot/efi
```

Or should I create `/boot/efi` directly in the volatile filesystem, using the following commands?

```
root@archiso ~ # mkdir /mnt/boot
root@archiso ~ # mount /dev/sdb1 /mnt/boot
```

Answer (score 1):

*Typically*, the EFI partition is mounted as `/boot/efi`.

The actual question on whether is a subdirectory of a permanent or temporary file system doesn't matter. All that matters is that the GRUB installer (or, specifically, `grub_probe`) finds it during installation. Setting it up permanently definitely sounds more convenient - else you'd have to recreate it every time a GRUB EFI shim update happesn (but that's rare, then again).